# Form validation on php not working

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

Hello I am trying to validate a form in php.The form will validate name,email, gender and password. For some reason I can still submit data and no message will be displayed meaning the validation code I have created in php doesn't work. I have also added php code on the form so it can display the error but nothing.I have seen tutorials and stuff online but still cant find the error.Can you help me figure out why is this happening? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation with PHP - Demo Preview</title>
<style>
.error{
    color:red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Initialize variables to null.
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";
$genderError ="";
$passwordError ="";


//kur shtypim butonin submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //ne rast se emri eshte bosh  
    if (empty($name)) {
        $nameError = "Vendosni emrin";
    } 

    // emri permban vetem shkronja dhe hapesira
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameError = "Lejohen vetem shkronja dhe hapesire te bardha";
    }

    //ne rast se email eshte bosh
    if (empty($email)) {
        $emailError = "Vendosni email";
    } 

    // pattern email
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
        $emailError = "Format i pavlefshem email";
    }


    if(empty($password)){
        $passwordError="Vendosni password";
    }

    //pattern password
    if(!preg_match("/^\w{6,10}$/", $password)){
        $passwordError="Passwordi duhet te jete 6 deri ne 10 karaktere"; 
    }

    if (empty($gender)) {
        $genderError = "Vendosni gjinine";
    } 
     }
//php code ends here
?>

    <h2>Form Validation with PHP.</h2>

    <form action="Ushtrimi3_2014.php" method="post">
    <h2>Form</h2>

        Emri:
        <input name="name" type="text" value="">
        <?php echo $nameError;?>
        E-mail:
        <input name="email" type="text" value="">
        <?php echo $emailError;?>
        Password:
        <input name="password" type="text" value="">
        <?php echo $passwordError;?>
        Gender:
        <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female">Female
        <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male">Male
        <?php echo $genderError;?>

        <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Why did you just remove the code that MIGHT just make this work????

Comment: Is this code ALL in a file called `Ushtrimi3_2014.php`

Comment: Yes all in that file. I just fixed some small stuff

Comment: if you place all this code in a file which you have given as value to the form action attribute then it will work its working with me.

Comment: Yeah it's in the same file, and I fixed the bracket before ending the php code but its not working

Comment: Where did you define `$name`, `$password`, `$email` and `$gender`?

Comment: Fixed it by writing $_POST['name'] instead of $name but one thing I cant get to work is that when an error happens all inputs are deleted and you have to write them all again. How can I do it so that only the one which has an error gets deleted and I have to rewrite only that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below to show both errors and correct values in inputs instead of deleting them:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation with PHP - Demo Preview</title>
<style>
.error{
    color:red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Initialize variables to null.
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";
$genderError ="";
$passwordError ="";


//kur shtypim butonin submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = $_POST['emri'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    //ne rast se emri eshte bosh  
    if (empty($name)) {
        $nameError = "Vendosni emrin";
    } 

    // emri permban vetem shkronja dhe hapesira
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameError = "Lejohen vetem shkronja dhe hapesire te bardha";
    }

    //ne rast se email eshte bosh
    if (empty($email)) {
        $emailError = "Vendosni email";
    } 

    // pattern email
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
        $emailError = "Format i pavlefshem email";
    }


    if(empty($password)){
        $passwordError="Vendosni password";
    }

    //pattern password
    if(!preg_match("/^\w{6,10}$/", $password)){
        $passwordError="Passwordi duhet te jete 6 deri ne 10 karaktere"; 
    }

    if (empty($gender)) {
        $genderError = "Vendosni gjinine";
    } 
     }
//php code ends here
?>

    <h2>Form Validation with PHP.</h2>

    <form action="Ushtrimi3_2014.php" method="post">
    <h2>Form</h2>

        Emri:
        <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php (isset($name)) ? echo $name : '';?>">
        <?php echo $nameError;?>
        E-mail:
        <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php (isset($email)) ? echo $email: '';?>">
        <?php echo $emailError;?>
        Password:
        <input name="password" type="text" value="<?php (isset($password)) ? echo $password: '';?>">
        <?php echo $passwordError;?>
        Gender:
        <input name="gender" type="radio" value="female" <?php (isset($gender) && $gender == 'female') ? echo selected: '';?>>Female
        <input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" <?php (isset($gender) && $gender == 'male') ? echo selected: '';?>>Male
        <?php echo $genderError;?>

        <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some errors in your code.
You forgot to closed the main if condition.
And variable should assign after press submit button
I rewrite you code 
it may be helpful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Validation with PHP - Demo Preview</title>
<style>
.error{
color:red
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
// Initialize variables to null.
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";
$genderError ="";
$passwordError ="";



//kur shtypim butonin submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){



//ne rast se emri eshte bosh  
if (empty($_POST['emri'])) {
$nameError = "Vendosni emrin";
} 

// emri permban vetem shkronja dhe hapesira
else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$_POST['emri'])) {
$nameError = "Lejohen vetem shkronja dhe hapesire te bardha";
}
else{
$name=$_POST['emri'];
}


//ne rast se email eshte bosh
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
$emailError = "Vendosni email";
} 

// pattern email
else if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$_POST['email'])) {
$emailError = "Format i pavlefshem email";
}
else{
$email=$_POST['email'];
}


if(empty($_POST['password'])){
$passwordError="Vendosni password";
 }

//pattern password
 else if(!preg_match("/^\w{6,10}$/", $_POST['password'])){
    $passwordError="Passwordi duhet te jete 6 deri ne 10 karaktere"; 
    }

  else{
    $password=$_POST['password'];
  }

if (empty($_POST['gender'])) {
$genderError = "Vendosni gjinine";
}
else{
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
}

}
//php code ends here
?>

<h2>Form Validation with PHP.</h2>

<form action="" method="post">
<h2>Form</h2>


Emri:
<input name="emri" type="text" value="<?=(isset($name)?$name:"")?>">
<?php echo $nameError;?>
E-mail:
<input name="email" type="text" value="<?=(isset($email)?$email:"")?>">
<?php echo $emailError;?>
Password:
<input name="password" type="text" value="<?=(isset($password)?    $password:"")?>">
<?php echo $passwordError;?>
Gender:
<input name="gender" type="radio" <?=(isset($gender) &&             ($gender=="female"))?"checked":""?> value="female">Female
<input name="gender" type="radio" <?=(isset($gender) && 
($gender=="male"))?"checked":""?> value="male">Male
<?php echo $genderError;?>


<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one thing I cant get to work is that when an error happens all inputs are deleted and you have to write them all again. How can I do it so that only the one which has an error gets deleted and I have to rewrite only that